# What's the right return type for passing through size_type and const_iterator?

Tags: c++, stl

I'm trying to create a set that doesn't require `<` or a hash function. I've created the following, but I'm not sure what the proper return types are for `size()`, `cbegin()`, and `cend()`. I've tried different combinations of `std::` and `deque<t>::` without much luck. I know the performance would theoretically be bad for this kind of object, but I never expect it to have more than 64 elements or so. I think this is likely mostly a syntax question.

```
#include <deque>
template <typename t> 
struct unordered_eq_set
{
public:
    //This is a set for items where < does not exist - inserts are O(N). 
    void insert(const t& item)
    {
        for (t& testItem : items)
        {
            if (testItem == item)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        items.insert(item);
        return;
    }
    std::deque<t>::size_type size()
    {
        return items.size();
    }
    std::deque<t>::const_iterator cbegin()
    {
        return items.cbegin();
    }
    std::deque<t>::const_iterator cend()
    {
        return items.cend();
    }

private:
    std::deque<t> items;
};
int main()
{
    unordered_eq_set<int> dumbSet;
    dumbSet.insert(3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do yo mean *without much luck*?  Are you getting compiler errors?  If so, what is the full error text?

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: You need `typename std::deque<t>::...` or just use auto or create typedef's for the different types